# Unable to start service Intent. Fora Dictionary

Tags: android, android-intent

i try translate a word via Fora Dictionary Api. [Here](http://ng-comp.com/fora/fora_api.txt) more about ForaApi. Here is my code:

```
                String query = "com.ngc.fora.action.QUERY";  


                Intent foraIntent = new Intent(query);
                foraIntent.putExtra("QUERY_ID", new Long("1"));
                foraIntent.putExtra("QUERY", lword);
                foraIntent.putExtra("MAX_RESULTS", 2);
                foraIntent.putExtra("AS_PAGE", true);
                foraIntent.putExtra("CALLBACK_ACTION", "com.myAPP.ServiceForFora.TRANSLATE");
                foraIntent.putExtra("CALLBACK_PACKAGE", "com.myAPP");
                foraIntent.putExtra("CALLBACK_CLASS", ".ServiceForFora");
                startService(foraIntent);
```

But when Fora Dictionary try send intent to my service(ServiceForFora) i get this:

***05-07 06:20:40.440: W/ActivityManager(52): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.myAPP.ServiceForFora.TRANSLATE cmp=com.myAPP/.ServiceForFora (has extras) }: not found***

Here's my service:

```
epublic class ServiceForFora extends Service{

@Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "onBind", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     
      return null;
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
      //code to execute when the service is first created
       Toast.makeText(this, "onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       super.onCreate();
   }

   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
      //code to execute when the service is shutting down
       super.onDestroy();
   }

   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      //code to execute when the service is starting up
       super.onStart(intent, startId);
       return Service.START_STICKY;
   }
```

}

and Manifest notation:

```
<application><service android:name="com.myAPP.ServiceForFora" 
             android:exported="true">          
             <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="com.myAPP.ServiceForFora.TRANSLATE"/>                                                            
             </intent-filter>
            </service>
             .............................             
    </application>
```

Thank's

Comment: Hi, did you figure out why it doesn't work? I have got the same situation:(

Answer (score 1):

try to remove this code :

```
foraIntent.putExtra("CALLBACK_PACKAGE", "com.myAPP");
foraIntent.putExtra("CALLBACK_CLASS", ".ServiceForFora");
```

and add more parameters to service description :

```
android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:stateNotNeeded="true" android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
```